# 20.04 -> 22.04 release "unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade"

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, release-management

In `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`

(earlier)

```
2023-07-31 12:38:07,292 ERROR NoDistroTemplateException raised: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/focal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-2ka77vmt/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 508, in rewriteSourcesList
    distro.get_sources(self.sources)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-2ka77vmt/DistUpgrade/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
DistUpgrade.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/focal
```

(later)

```
2023-07-31 12:40:03,598 ERROR failed to mark 'kubuntu-desktop' for install (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-07-31 12:40:03,694 DEBUG denylist expr 'update-manager$' matches 'update-manager'
2023-07-31 12:40:03,694 DEBUG The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it's in the removal deny list
2023-07-31 12:40:03,722 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it is in the removal deny list.'
2023-07-31 12:40:03,735 DEBUG abort called
```

(full log files)
https://gandsnut.net/temp/apt.log
https://gandsnut.net/temp/main.log

Have tried apt-get update and upgrade, apt autoremove, the release upgrade process fails when running "sudo do-release-upgrade"

Not sure how to go forward.  TY...

Comment: Which desktop are you running? I see budgie and kubuntu installed.

Comment: I mostly use KDE Plasma.  I have Budgie, XFCE, and some Gnome desktops as well.  For those, each has a particular user login.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` to force install any of the broken packages?

Comment: @Terrance:  Yes, I tried apt -f install.  It did not force install.  At this point, I've decided to do a fresh install of 22.04, getting rid of 20.04 and its broken packages.  Thanks.